# How to validate the response of my java service in angular?

Tags: java, angular, spring-boot

I have a Java service that queries the database and returns a list of data which I must show in a table in my front with angular, so I did this method that returns a hash map to know if an error occurred when querying or to know that there is no data in the date range so it returns an error code since I want to validate this code in the front and  show a message in my front that there is no data or that an error occurred in addition to showing the

Java Controller

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200")
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/consultValues")
public class ValuesController {
    
    @GetMapping
    public Map<String, Object>  consultValues(
            @RequestParam(required = false, value = "startDate") Integer startDate,
            @RequestParam(required = false, value = "endDate") Integer endDate) throws Exception {
        Map<String, Object>  listValues = new HashMap<>();
        try {
            listValues = valuesService.listValues(startDate, endDate);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOGGER.error("Error in Values ");
            throw e;
        }
        return listValues;
    }

}
```

Java Service

```
@Override
public Map<String, Object> listValues(Integer startDate, Integer endDate) throws Exception {
    Map<String, Object> response = new HashMap<>();
    List<ValuesDto> list = new ArrayList<ValuesDto>();
    try {
        Integer start = startDate;
        Integer end = endDate;
        list = valuesRepository.findByDates(start, end);
        if (list.isEmpty() || list == null) {
            LOGGER.error("There is not values");
            response.put("Error", 400);
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOGGER.error("An error ocurred");
        response.put("Error", 500);
        response.put("error", e.getMessage());
        throw e;
    }
    response.put("success", true);
    response.put("data", list);
    return response;

}
```

Now in my front I have this method of my service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import {ValoresDto} from '../Models/ValoresDTO';

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ConsultValuesService {

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
    Url = 'http://localhost:8080/consultValues';


    consultValues(startDate:any, endDate:any){
        return this.http.get<ValuesDTO[]>(this.Url+ `?startDate=${startDate}&endDate=${endDate}`);
    }
}
```

In my Component.ts I have this method but I dont know how to validate the response of my java service, for example if my java service returns a code error 400 means that there is not data and show a message with Swal, if returns 500 ocurred an error and show the message with Swal too, or sucees return the list and fill my table

```
getValuesDB() {
    if (this.valuesForm.valid) {
        this.service.consultValues(this.endDate, this.endDate).subscribe({
        next: data => {
        this.modelConsultValues=data;
        },
         error: (err) => console.error(err),
         complete: () => console.log('Completed')
        });
  

    } else {
        Swal.fire({
        icon: 'error',
        text: 'You must select both dates'
        })
    }
}
```

anyone helps me please, how can I validate the response of my java service and show the table fill or the messages

Answer (score 0):

This is **highly opinionated** but I will post a link anyway. `class-validator` let's you spice up models with decorators and then validate the instances.

https://github.com/typestack/class-validator